# Nombrar a un backup pero que no coincida con el anterior C#

Tags: c#, rutas, file

Mi código hace un backup de una carpeta, si la carpeta backup existe crea otra añadiendo "_1" y si no existe crea una nueva. No sé como hacer para que cuando  haya más de una carpeta backup genere otra automáticamente sin que coincida el nombre, os dejo aquí el código que he conseguido hasta ahora:

```
//backup del directorio destino en otra carpeta
private static void directoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
{
    // Get the subdirectories for the specified directory.
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);
    DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();



    if (!dir.Exists)
    {
        throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
            "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
            + sourceDirName);
    }

    if (Directory.Exists(destDirName))
    {
        destDirName = destDirName + "_1";
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
    }
    else
    // If the destination directory doesn't exist, create it. 
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
    }

    // Get the files in the directory and copy them to the new location.
    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
        file.CopyTo(temppath, false);
    }

    // If copying subdirectories, copy them and their contents to new location. 
    if (copySubDirs)
    {
        foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
        {
            string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);
            directoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Es necesario que sea `_numero`? Es posible que el nombre de la carpeta ya contenga el caracter `_`?

Comment: no es necesario. Sí es posible, claro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay muchas soluciones a tu problema. Puedes, como te dicen en otra respuesta,usar la fecha y la hora. Puedes usar un guid para que siempre sea única la carpeta.

Yo te doy una solución para que las carpetas siempre acaben en un numero secuencial (_1,_2,_3...). No está muy optimizada, pero te puede ayudar a ver como hacerlo:

```
while (Directory.Exists(destDirName)) //repetimos hasta que no exista el directorio
{
    int indice = 0;
    var splitted = destDirName.Split('_'); //separamos el nombre para obtener el número secuencial

    if (int.TryParse(splitted.Last(), out indice))
    {
        //si la última parte del nombre es un numero, lo incrementamos
        indice++;
    }

    if (splitted.Length > 1)
    {
        //unimos el nombre de la carpera quitando la última parte (_X) 
        //y le añadimos el nuevo indice
        destDirName = String.Join("", splitted.Reverse().Skip(1).Reverse()) + "_" + indice.ToString(); 
    }
    else
    {
        //si no era un número, añadimos _1
        destDirName+= "_" + indice.ToString();
    }
}

//una vez tenemos un nombre único, creamos la carpeta
Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda de nuevo! voy a añadirle también la fecha